# Filter an array by two different criteria

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have the below code which uses a `controller` to grab the contents of a JSON file and then display the first 5 results.  The code also includes a filter to allow users to search.

The filter looks for results in both `name` and `code` (see below JSON example), which is great.  However, I'd like for the filter to do more;  `code` is unique, and if a match to code is found it should be displayed at the top of the list, with the remaining four results listed by `name` underneath.

For example, if the user was to search for `swi`, currently the five results that are listed are -

> Brunswick (BRW)
> Chiswick (CHK)
> Derby Road (Ipswich) (DBR)
> Giggleswick (GIG)
> Hutton Cranswick (HUT)

What I would like is -

> Swindon (SWI)
> Brunswick (BRW)
> Chiswick (CHK)
> Derby Road (Ipswich) (DBR)
> Giggleswick (GIG)

Is this possible using AngularJS, or would I be looking at using some more complex logic to get my desired results?

---

## JSON example

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abbey Wood",
    "code": "ABW"
  },
  {
    "name": "Aber",
    "code": "ABE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abercynon",
    "code": "ACY"
  }
]
```

---

## My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB" data-ng-app="tigerSelector">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tiger | Staff CIS Selector</title>
    
    <!-- Mobile stuff -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    
    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var app = angular.module('tigerSelector', []);
        
        app.controller('stationsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('stations.json').then(function(res){
                $scope.stations = res.data;                
            });
        });
    
    </script>
    
</head>

<body>

<div data-ng-controller="stationsCtrl">

    <p>Filtering input:</p>

    <p><input type="text" data-ng-model="search"></p>

    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="station in stations | filter:search | orderBy:'name' | limitTo:5">
            {{ station.name }} ({{ (station.code | uppercase) }})
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would need your own sort function to be able to prioritize sort...which would lead to creating custom filter

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks, I've just discovered custom filters and am investigating now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom filter, and iterate over your collection, and passing your `search` ngModel to the filter.

**Filter**

```
(function(){

  function filter(){
    return function (input, search) {
      var out = [];
      //Map over the input
      [].map.call(input || [], function(elm){
        //Compare code value to search model
         elm.code.toLowerCase() === search
         //Push elm at the beginning of the array
         ? out.unshift(elm)
         //Otherwise, add element to the end of the array
         : out.push(elm);
       });

       //Return our filtered array
       return out;
   };
  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('myFilter', filter);

})();
```

Then you can call your filter into your template. You can combine multiple filter.

**HTML**

```
<p><input type="text" data-ng-model="search"></p>

<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="station in stations | myFilter:search | filter:search | limitTo:5">
        {{ station.name }} ({{ (station.code | uppercase) }})
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what I needed.  I have made two slight amendments - 1) To avoid an error (`search` is undefined), a check to see if `search` has been defined in the `filter()` function (I return `input` if not). 2) Changed `elm.code.toLowerCase() === search` to `elm.code.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()` to make the seach case insensitive.